# Laravel saves temp file as image

Tags: laravel

I have 3 image field for my products, on save method all working fine, but in update method `first image` saves temp file in database and the other two update without issue.

## Code

Here I share all my 3 images on update method:

```
//saves temp file instead of file name
if ($request->hasFile('imageOne')) {
            $imageOne = $request->file('imageOne');
            $filename = 'productone' . '-' . time() . '.' . $imageOne->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = storage_path('app/public/images/' . $filename);
            Image::make($imageOne)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);

            if(!empty($product->imageOne)){
                Storage::delete('images/' . $product->imageOne);
            }
            $product->imageOne = $imageOne;            
        }
//works with no issue
        if ($request->hasFile('imageTwo')) {
            $imageTwo = $request->file('imageTwo');
            $filename = 'producttwo' . '-' . time() . '.' . $imageTwo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = storage_path('app/public/images/' . $filename);
            Image::make($imageTwo)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);

            if(!empty($product->imageTwo)){
                Storage::delete('images/' . $product->imageTwo);
            }
            $product->imageTwo = $filename;            
        }
//works with no issue
        if ($request->hasFile('imageThree')) {
            $imageThree = $request->file('imageThree');
            $filename = 'productthree' . '-' . time() . '.' . $imageThree->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = storage_path('app/public/images/' . $filename);
            Image::make($imageThree)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);

            if(!empty($product->imageThree)){
                Storage::delete('images/' . $product->imageThree);
            }
            $product->imageThree = $filename;            
        }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is here:-

```
$product->imageOne = $imageOne;
```

You are saving $imageOne. But you need to save $filename. Use following code:-

```
$product->imageOne = $filename;
```

Comment: bless you <3 :)